Getting this error while build creation ;java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userFormData’ : Injection of autowired dependencies failed Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'report.dt.size’ in value "${report.dt.size}”
I have defined a property in application.yaml as given below
report:
  dt:
    size: 11

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserFormData extends AnAbstractClass {
    @Value(“${report.dt.size}”)
    private int size;
    Private final AnyOtherClass anyOtherClass;   //AnyOtherClass is a component 

    @Override
    SomeMethod

}

I am trying to get the value but encountered above mentioned issue.
Thanks in advance
